# Why does Lucee prepend a leading space character when I directly output values returned from a <cffunction> and how do I stop it?

Tags: function, coldfusion, cfml, removing-whitespace, lucee

I'm having a very strange issue with output from a function. I have a basic function for sanitizing user inputs. When I try to output the function result I get the value prepended with a space. If I assign the function result to a variable and then output that variable, the space is not present. Here's an example of what I'm talking about. Imagine there is a function called fn_SanitizeInput().

```
<cfset var_UserInput = "foo">
<cfset var_SanitizedUserInput = fn_SanitizeInput(var_UserInput)>  // foo

<cfoutput>

    Input Length: #len(var_UserInput)#          // 3
    Sanitized Input Length:
        #len(fn_SanitizeInput(var_UserInput))#  // 3
        #len(var_SanitizedUserInput)#           // 3

    Function Output: |#fn_SanitizeInput(var_UserInput)#|                // | foo|
    Trimmed Function Output: |#trim(fn_SanitizeInput(var_UserInput))#|  // | foo|
    Var Output: |#var_SanitizedUserInput#|                              // |foo|

</cfoutput>
```

I don't understand why the len() function returns 3, but four characters are displayed when I print the result. And since trimming the function still gives me the leading space, I feel like the function result is correct and that Lucee is adding the space for some unknown reason when it performs the evaluation. Has anyone else run into this? I can just assign all the results to a variable first if I need to, but I'd still like to know why this is happening.

Comment: Not related to the function but the output buffer. Unless you have `<cfsetting enableCFoutputOnly="true">` and `output="false"` everywhere, eventually whitespaces will be appended to the output buffer. Check the HTML source view of the page you are printing here. You will probably notice lots of whitespaces, which are reduced to single gaps by the browser's rendering. ACF and Lucee offer "whitespace management" in the admin panel, you might want to check that out.

Comment: What does your function look like? Does it have `output="false"` set?

Comment: Wow, this is interesting.  What I did was copy your code and create a gist at https://trycf.com/gist/ec8630b05941b31fd3f711283353d92a/lucee5?theme=monokai with your function `fn_SanitizeInput()` which simply returns the argument passed in as is (nothing sanitized).  What I also found is the anomaly you presented exists in both acf and lucee.  It almost makes me wonder that when ColdFusion outputs a complex expression, it's prepending a blank space, but when it outputs a variable, then it doesn't???  Most peculiar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**

Change

```
<cffunction name="fn_SanitizeInput">
    <cfargument name="arg">
    <cfreturn arguments.arg>
</cffunction>
```

To

```
<cffunction name="fn_SanitizeInput" output="false">
    <cfargument name="arg">
    <cfreturn arguments.arg>
</cffunction>
```

**Longer answer**

Where did the space come from?

The space is from the end of `<argument>` tag to the start of the `<cfreturn>` tag. If you really wanted to, you could

```
<cffunction name="fn_SanitizeInput"><cfargument name="arg"><cfreturn arguments.arg></cffunction>
```

The code you wrote may have looked like:

```
#len(fn_SanitizeInput(var_UserInput))#
```

But in reality, it was something like this:

```
 <cfsavecontent var="result">#fn_SanitizeInput(var_UserInput)#</cfsavecontent>

 #len(result)#
```

**Some editorializing**

I really wish the cfml default output mode for functions was silent, but alas it is not. For my own sanity, I set `output="false"` so I don't have to worry about it.

Comment: "I really wish the cfml default output mode for functions was silent" It is if you use script instead of tags.

Comment: @DanBracuk Thanks for catching that. Answer fixed

Comment: Great answer @JamesAMohler!  Here's a link to a question about the `output="false"` option where Adam Cameron explains the tri-state nature of the output option.https://community.adobe.com/t5/ColdFusion/lt-cfcomponent-output-quot-false-quot-gt/td-p/3489012

Comment: That was it, thank you! Of course it's something that simple after I tear my hair out for an hour.

Comment: I thought output from function was separate from the return value. TIL

Comment: @DanRoberts : Functions do two things at the same time. They generate something that can be returned. They also generate content that gets sent to the browser. Unless output="false", all the spaces, tabs, newlines, etc are also sent.

Comment: @JamesAMohler I misread and thought output was being interpreted by the wrapping function. It is actually working the way I expected and just being output.